# How to identify if a number string is all repeating digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Using Excel 2010, I was looking for the easiest way to add a check column that will identify "dummy numbers" by checking if a number string is all repeating digits (i.e. serial number 99999999).

I attempted to use =MOD() and divide by digits 1,2,3...9 but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this formula to be exactly what I needed so I thought I would share for anyone else looking.

```
=VALUE(REPT(LEFT(A1,1),LEN(A1)))=A1
```

[image: excel 2010 - identify if number is all repeating digits]